# How to find pdf of transformed r.v using joint distribution

Tags: probability, data-transformation, random-variable, density-function, joint-distribution

I'm intrigued by the following idea but I don't know how to do it.

If I have a r.v. $x$ with given distribution $f_X(x)$ and I have a second variable $y=2x$. The goal is to find $f_Y(y)$.

I know the traditional solution, but, can I say that from $y=2x$, I can conclude that $f(y\mid x)=2x \cdot \delta(y-2x)$ ?? If that is correct, then I can form the joint $f(x,y)$ then I can marginalize out $x$ to reach my goal.

I'm trying to do it but I'm missing something.

Comment: It's tricky to work with $\delta$ correctly and even trickier to generalize it to multiple dimensions as you propose.  (The only truly general ways to analyze potentially degenerate joint distributions are to work with the joint CDF or quantities that can always be derived from it, such as the joint characteristic function.)  Could you explain what it is you are missing?

Comment: @whuber It's totally fine to solve it just for 1D. I don't want the generalized form. What I feel is missing is dy/dx or $dx/dy$, it some how gotta be involved in $f(x,y)$. Currently, without it, $f(x,y)=f(y|x)f(x)$ is not normalized.

Comment: Maybe you mean $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ instead of $f_x(x)$ and $f_y(y). \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Correct. Thanks.

Comment: You are asking an inherently 2D question--you have two random variables--so I don't understand what you mean by "solve it just for 1D."

Comment: @whuber I mean that both $f(x)$ and my goal, $f(y)$ are 1D distributions.

Comment: Yes, but your question seems explicitly to ask about "form the joint $f(x,y)$."  If that's not what you mean to ask, then what is your question??

Comment: @JohnDeterious : If $x=3$ then $f(x) = f(3),$ and if $y = 3$ then $f(y) = f(3),$ so is $f(3)$ a value of the density function of (capital) $X$ or of (capital) $Y$? On the other hand $f_X(3)$ (with a capitlized subscript) and $f_Y(3)$ (likewise) are clear. So what you need is $f_X$ and $f_Y,$ not $f(x)$ and $f(y).$ This sort of thing can make a practical difference in writing some proofs that arise in exercises and elsewhere. $\qquad$

Comment: You must have meand $Y=2X$ rather than $y=2x. \qquad$

Comment: Instead of $2x\delta(y-2x),$ I would expect something like $f_X(x)\delta(y-2x),$ possibly multiplied by a suitable constant.

Comment: If one is to speak of this kind of joint density, it would need to be a generalized function $f$ having the property that for subsets $A$ of the plane $\mathbb R^2,$ you have $$ \iint\limits_A f(x,y)\,d(x,y) = \Pr\big( (X,Y)\in A\big). $$